# Pass array values to the next page (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm doing a short quiz and i would like to know how can i pass over the quiz answers to the next page?

My Quiz page

```
<?php
$qtspool =
      array(  1=> array('qts'=>'What is my name?', 'ans'=>'Lu'),
              2=> array('qts'=>'What is the module code?', 'ans'=>'307'),
              3=> array('qts'=>'What is missing char abde?', 'ans'=>'c'),
              4=> array('qts'=>'What is missing number 1345?', 'ans'=>'2')
      );
      
      $qtspick_key = array_rand($qtspool,3);
      for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
      {
          $qtspick_key[$i];
      }
      
      $pickqts = array();
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($qtspick_key as $key)
      {
          $pickqts[$i] = $qtspool[$key]; 
          $i++;
      }
      
      
      ?>
      
      <form method="get" action="abc.php" >
        <br>
        <?php 
            foreach($pickqts as $qtsno=>$value)
        {
            ?>
            <?php echo $value['qts']; ?>
            <input name="user_ans" type="text" >
            <input type="hidden" name="answers" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value['ans']); ?>" />           
            
            <br>
            <?php

            
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

I tried `<input type="hidden" name="answers" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value['ans']); ?>" />` but it could only pass over the last answer of the question to the next page.

P.S: when I do an `echo $value['ans'];`, I'm able to return all the answers of the randomized questions on the quiz page.

Comment: are you need to `foreach($_GET['answers'] as $ans){ echo $ans;}` sorround it with if isset for safety in the page you are recieving ans

Comment: You could also use $_SESSION to store all the answer in the current session. This way you would have all the answer saved in a current session without the fear of losing them and passing all the answers between pages.

Comment: @Mark he is already getting the last answer with this procedure so i dont think changing procedure will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send variables by array so change the lines:

```
<input name="user_ans" type="text" >
<input type="hidden" name="answers" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value['ans']); ?>" />
```

to:

```
<input name="user_ans[]" type="text" >
<input type="hidden" name="answers[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value['ans']); ?>" />
```